# Spring custom PropertyEditor / Converters not recognized : no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, web-services, reflection, spring-ws

I am calling a SOAP WS using Spring's WebServiceGatewaySupport and using reflection to set the request values. Spring version is 4.2.4.RELEASE and Spring WS version is 3.0.7.RELEASE.

Some of the expected attributes are of type XmlGregorianCalendar, so I created a custom XmlGregorianCalendarPropertyEditor for String<->XmlGregorianCalendar casting :

```
@Slf4j
public class XmlGregorianCalendarPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = (XMLGregorianCalendar) getValue();
    if (xmlGregorianCalendar != null) {
        df.setTimeZone(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeZone());
        return df.format(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(text)) {
        setValue(null);
    } else {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            calendar.setTime(df.parse(text));
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
            setValue(xmlGregorianCalendar);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            log.error("Error parsing date {}", text);
            setValue(null);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            log.error("Error building XmlGregorianCalendar!");
            setValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This code could probably be better, I haven't been able to test it yet.

I have tried different ways of registering my PropertyEditor within my @Configuration class, but none have worked. Here's how it is right now :

```
@Bean
public CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
    CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    customEditorConfigurer.setCustomEditors(Collections.singletonMap(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, XmlGregorianCalendarPropertyEditor.class));
    return customEditorConfigurer;
}
```

Reflection-wise, I have a BeanWrapperImpl on the Request class and I simply use its method setPropertyValue(attributeName, value).

Here's the exception message I get :

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar] for property 'dateCreationDocument'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar] for property 'dateCreationDocument': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I also tried creating two Converters and added this to my @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
    StringToXmlGregorianCalendar stringToXmlGregorianCalendar = new StringToXmlGregorianCalendar();
    XmlGregorianCalendarToString xmlGregorianCalendarToString = new XmlGregorianCalendarToString();
    converters.add(stringToXmlGregorianCalendar);
    converters.add(xmlGregorianCalendarToString);
    conversionServiceFactoryBean.setConverters(converters);
    return conversionServiceFactoryBean;
}
```

But that leads to the same exception. I guess I could use the converters programatically (using @Autowired) but then that would mean more code and unnecessary type checking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using this line everytime I used a BeanWrapperImpl:

```
BeanWrapperImpl beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(request);
beanWrapper.registerCustomEditor(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, new XmlGregorianCalendarPropertyEditor());
```

Not the most clean way to do things but it works.

Also, be careful with the CustomEditorConfigurer, I didn't make the bean static and it broke the annotations in my @Configuration class (so I couldn't use @Value for instance). Here's the warning that Spring gave me:

> @Bean method ApplicationConfig.customEditorConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.